# Mostrar resultados de mysql de mayor a menor numero de vistas

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Quiero crear un buscador Interno para mi pagina con PHP. y que la pagina Muestre los resultados de mayor a menor numero de vistas ( las vistas están almacenadas en MySQL ). Pero No encuentro la forma de hacerlo. De que manera seria Posible?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo, es crear un campo en la base de datos que sea visitas e incrementarlo cada vez que se accede a una página.

Luego puedes sacar una `SELECT` de las páginas más visitadas usando un `ORDER BY visitas DESC`